# Upload a File to a Task on Cerb API

Tags: php, file-upload

At the moment I am adding a task to Cerb using the API (Docs: https://cerb.ai/docs/api/). I can add and edit comments on the task. 
An extension is to add file uploads. The API documentation seems to be extremely limited in terms of file uploads and isn't helping much. I have based my current code on https://cerb.ai/docs/api/endpoints/records/#update, using a custom field linked to the task and posting directly to the API.

The process is as follows:
1 - User inserts information on a Laravel form
2 - Form is submitted, task is created
3 - If the user entered a comment or description, the controller then uses the ID from the newly created task toa dd the comment
4 - If the user adds a file, the controller should then use the same ID from the task to attach the file

Task and comment adding has been done through models, which were previously done directly through the API and reformatted once they worked.

Add Task:

```
        $params = [
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'links' => ['project:'.$request->input('project')],
            'priority' => $request->input('priority'),
            'status_id' => 2 
        ];

        $due_date = $request->input('due');
        if(!empty($due_date)){
            $params['due'] = strtotime($due_date); 
        }

        $success_task = $task->addUpdateRecord('tasks.add', $params);
```

Add Comment:

```
        $params = [
            'author__context' => 'bot',
            'author_id' => 3,
            'comment' => empty($comment_input) ? request()->comment : $comment_input,
            'target__context' => 'task',
            'target_id' => $task_id,
            'author' => Auth::user()->name      // custom field
        ];

        $success = $comment->addUpdateRecord('comments.add', $params);
```

The `addUpdateRecord()` essentially does the same thing as the file upload as below:

```
        $cerb = new CerbApi();
        $out = $cerb->put($root.'records/file_bundle/1054.json?expand=custom_', $putfields);
```

`$putfields` contains a normal file upload object.

I'm getting the following error on request:

```
array:2 [▼
  "__status" => "error"
  "message" => "Unknown command (root/records/task/1054.json)"
]
```

(root removed for confidentiality)

Has anyone worked with this? Anyone able to assist?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up getting it right by using the attachments record type https://cerb.ai/docs/records/types/attachment/ and creating a model for it with its own `addUpdateRecord()` method.

I then used the records API to do the post for the file as the first step instead of the last one:

```
$file_upload = new File;
        // Get file contents
        $data = file_get_contents($file);
        // Base64 encode contents
        $data = base64_encode($data);

        $file_params = [
            'name' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
            'content' => $data
        ];

        // Do upload
        $file_success = $file_upload->addUpdateRecord('files.add', $file_params);

        // Only need to return the file ID to link it to the task
        return $file_success["data"]["id"];
```

And then using the ID that was being returned to link it to the task:

```
$task = new Task();
        $params = [
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'links' => [
                'project:'.$request->input('project'),
                'file:'.$file_id
            ],
            'priority' => $request->input('priority'),
            'status_id' => 2 
        ];
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.

*Note: Cerb API Version 9.2.0*